# Python, removing items from list of buttons

Tags: python, list, button

So I have this code that reads in a spreadsheet to a dataframe, and then I have two functions that run when buttons are pressed. The first creates a list of new buttons for every column in the dataframe. The second is meant to wipe the list of buttons clear and delete the buttons from the screen.

I am having two issues. First, the building of the buttons in the first function works fine, but the list is weird. In my sample data, there are four columns. The buttons start as "...button" and then got to "...button2", "...button3", "...button4". I have no idea why there don't go either 0,1,2,3 or 1,2,3,4.

Then when I am deleting buttons in the second function, it crashes when it gets to the third button. No idea why. I am both removing the buttons from the grid and getting them out of the button list. I tried clearing the list as a whole instead of deleting every button as it steps through the list, but that hasn't worked. I tried several methods, as follows:

```
self.column_buttons = []
del self.column_buttons[:]
self.column_buttons.clear()
```

None of those will empty the list. If I build the button list, then use any of the above to try and clear it, then build it again, the buttons in the ist are 5-8, re-clearing and re-building then gets me 9-12, and so on.

Here is my code....

```
def fxThree(self):
    print(self.column_buttons)
    # make a new button in a new frame for each column in the file            
    for x in range(len(self.df1_columns)):
        self.new_button = tk.Button(self.frame3, text=self.df1_columns[x], command=lambda x=x: delete_button(self, x))
        self.new_button.grid(row=10, column=(x))
        self.column_buttons.append(self.new_button)

    print(self.column_buttons)
    print("\n")


def fxFour(self):
    for x in range(len(self.column_buttons)):
        print(x)
        print("Removing button: " + str(x))
        self.column_buttons[x].grid_remove()
        print("Deleting list entry :" + str(x))
        del self.column_buttons[x]
    del self.column_buttons[:]
    print(self.column_buttons)
```

This is what the output from the first function looks like in the console:

```
[<tkinter.Button object .!frame3.!button>, <tkinter.Button object .!frame3.!button2>, <tkinter.Button object .!frame3.!button3>, <tkinter.Button object .!frame3.!button4>]
```

This is the output and error from the second function:

```
0
Removing button: 0
Deleting list entry :0
1
Removing button: 1
Deleting list entry :1
2
Removing button: 2
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/user/Documents/Data Management/Python/SheetMapper/sheet_mapper_01.3.py", line 312, in fxFour
    self.column_buttons[x].grid_remove()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I even tried having it iterate backwards starting at the last entry in case I was wiping out entries as I went, and still got a not in index error.